# How to add space between accordion panels in native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Accordion component from Native Base.
I have added custom render for header and content.
How to add space between items loaded or is there a way to add border and the end of each section?

```
  <Accordion
   dataArray={dataArray}
   headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fffff' }}
   expanded={0}
   renderContent={renderContent}
   renderHeader={renderHeader}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `style` prop to the `accordion`, with property of `marginTop:10` as such. Hope this will work!

```
<Accordion
   style={{marginTop:10}}
   dataArray={dataArray}
   headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fffff' }}
   expanded={0}
   renderContent={renderContent}
   renderHeader={renderHeader}
/>
```

Comment: As of now I can't think of any!